# Monitoring webpage with live auction

Tags: python, web-scraping, html

I was wondering, is there a tool for monitoring pages ? To be precise, let's say I would like to monit a webpage with live auctions of cars. Just to get item and price, and I can only monit it live. Unfortunetely prices are not visible before and after auction.

One auction (one car - live bidding) lasts for about 30s to 1 minute.

What would I like to do is just run my app which will be live monitoring those bids. Is that even possible ? If it is - what is the way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way is to download the page with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library every given interval and parse the html page with [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.
There are some other libraries for bigger scraping projects if you attend on monitoring a large number of auctions, although this as well can be accomplished with the libraries I noted.
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the page is not being refreshed. So I would need to make a lot of requests and I would like to avoid that. Because only dealers can view the page, so they can easily track back to me.

Comment: Can you add some more information about the page? Are the auctions appear and refreshed without you refreshing the page? I think you need to do some research and see how the site works. Maybe Selenium can help you more.

Comment: It's written in .NET. Page is not refreshed after each auction. All auctions are loaded, and they are all live. When one auction ends, the other one starts instantly. Selenium is not going to work, because it needs a scenario to work with. And I need to wait on the results, on the new info all the time.

Comment: Open the website with Chrome, Press F12 to open developer tools. Now go to network tab and watch what happens. All of the data fetched from the server can be viewed there. All you have to do is imitate the browser behavior by requesting the same data from the server. Requests can do that quite well.